# php array of rows and columns

Tags: php

My current array that I am making produce a different result than I am wanting.

I want to have this kind of out put

```
Row: 0: Column: 1: ID 1  
Row: 1: Column: 1: ID 1 
Row: 0: Column: 2: ID 2   
Row: 1: Column: 2: ID 2   
Row: 2: Column: 2: ID 2   
Row: 3: Column: 2: ID 2  
Row: 0: Column: 3: ID 3  
Row: 1: Column: 3: ID 3
```

As you can see the Rows and columns change based on the ID. So if the ID is same it just go to next row in the same column.   However if id is changed it goes to next column and rows start.

Currently I my code looks like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($pv->rawData); $i++) {   
 $relative=0; 
 $relativeTypeID = -1;  
 if ($pv->rawData[$i]->relativeTypeID != $relativeTypeID) {  
   $relativeTypeID = $pv->rawData[$i]->relativeTypeID;   
   $iTypeCount++;  
 }  
 if(!empty($pv->rawData[$i]->description)) {  
   $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][0] = $pv->rawData[$i]->description;  
   echo "Row: ".$i.": Column: ".$iTypeCount.": ID".$relativeTypeID." <br>";  
 }  
}
```

It gives me the following output

```
Row: 0: Column: 1: ID1  
Row: 1: Column: 2: ID1  
Row: 2: Column: 3: ID2   
Row: 3: Column: 4: ID2  
Row: 4: Column: 5: ID2   
Row: 5: Column: 6: ID2   
Row: 6: Column: 7: ID2  
Row: 7: Column: 8: ID2   
Row: 8: Column: 9: ID2   
Row: 9: Column: 10: ID2  
Row: 10: Column: 11: ID2   
Row: 11: Column: 12: ID2   
Row: 12: Column: 13: ID2  
….  
….
```

As you can see the Row and Columns are changing but not with ID number.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, so I might be wrong here, but I believe part of your question is that you want `$i` to be non-sequential, which doesn't make sense. I hope this doesn't sound rude, but this is pretty basic stuff. Or I could be completely misunderstanding your question. Is there some way you can clarify or provide more context?

Comment: Can you post a `print_r` of the array in question. That'll help.

Comment: isn't the ID the same thing as the COLUMN value in the above example...

seems you don't need to calculate the ID, just use the column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't (won't) decipher that for loop you've thrown up there. If you could provide a var_dump() of your $pv->rawData array I could do something better, but in pseudo-code:

```
foreach($column as $i => $col) {
    foreach($col->row as $j => $thing) {
        echo "Row: $j: Column: $i: ID {$thing->id}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you  for your reply. here is var dump  
array  
  0 =>   
    object(stdClass)[17]  
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '1' (length=1)  
      public 'relation' => string 'Mother' (length=6)  
      public 'description' => string 'Anemia' (length=6)  
  1 =>   
    object(stdClass)[18]  
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '1' (length=1)  
      public 'relation' => string 'Mother' (length=6)  
      public 'description' => string 'Alcoholism' (length=10)

Comment: 5 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'hiddenByUser' => string 'cccc' (length=27)
      public 'hiddenByClinic' => string 'ccc’ (length=26)
     
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'relation' => string 'Father' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string 'HEADACHE ' (length=23)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '2' (length=1))
      public 'relation' =>

Comment: string 'Father' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string ' 00142' (length=19)
  7 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'relation' => string 'Father' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string 'Alcoholism' (length=10)
      
  8 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
     
      public 'relativeTypeID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'relation' => string 'Father' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string 'Alcoholism' (length=10)